# UIpopoverController dealloc reached while popover is still visible in Ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller, popover

I am showing the camera roll using popover and user is able to select a picture and have that be shown in the `UIImageView`.

The code below will present the picker but upon clicking on a picture I get an NSexception. I've looked at similar questions on here, and google and found no solution. My popover is set to strong. Any help would be appreciated

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Pilot.h"

@interface PilotViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIPopoverControllerDelegate>




@property (readonly, nonatomic) UIImage                     *viewImage;

@property (weak, nonatomic    ) IBOutlet UIImageView        *imageView;

@property (nonatomic, strong  ) UIPopoverController         *popoverController;
@property (strong, retain     ) UIImagePickerController     *imagePicker;
```

//PilotViewController.m

```
#import "PilotViewController.h"

@interface PilotViewController ()


@end

@implementation PilotViewController
@synthesize popoverController;
@synthesize imagePicker;
@synthesize imageView;






//Button to open library
- (IBAction)library:(id)sender{

    //Create image picker controller

    self.imagePicker  = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];

    //Set source to the photo library
    self.imagePicker.delegate       = self;
   self. imagePicker.sourceType     = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    self.imagePicker.allowsEditing  = NO;

    self.popoverController          = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                                       initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
    self.popoverController.delegate = self;
    CGRect popoverRect = [self.view convertRect:[self.view frame]
                                       fromView:[self.view superview]];

    popoverRect.size.width = MIN(popoverRect.size.width, 80) ;
    popoverRect.origin.x  = popoverRect.origin.x+150;

    [self.popoverController
     presentPopoverFromRect:popoverRect
     inView:self.view
     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft
     animated:YES];
}



-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didfinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
                  editingInfo: (NSDictionary *) editinginfo
{
    imageView.image                = image;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}






- (IBAction)camera:(id)sender{


    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])

    {

     //Create image picker controller

    self.imagePicker                = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];

    self.imagePicker.delegate       = self;
    self.imagePicker.sourceType=
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    self.imagePicker.allowsEditing  = NO;

    self.imagePicker.cameraDevice =
    UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

    else
    {
    UIAlertView *alert      = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Camera failed to open"
                              message:@"Camera is not available"
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }




}

#pragma mark Image Picker Delegate Methods

//on cancel dimiss picker controller

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


}

//Used when user has chosen an image

- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage * image                 = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    imageView.image                = image;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}



    @end





- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    if ([picker sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]){
        UIImage * image                 = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        imageView.image                 = image;
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


    }else{


   UIImage * image                 = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
   imageView.image                 = image;
}

          }

    @end
```

Comment: Which line gives the exception. Also your property declaration for the image picker doesn't look right - strong and retain are essentially the same.

Comment: It doesn't show a line, just the generic main.m file when it crashes. And yeah that was a mistake, I've assigned it to nonatomic, strong and still get the same nsexception

Comment: @Paulw11 do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint in the breakpoint navigator

Comment: a generic one? or should I have a specific action for it

Comment: Just an all exceptions breakpoint

Comment: okay doing so points to the line @implementation PilotViewController

Comment: What is the exception message Try enabling NSZombies http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode

Comment: Exception message is UIPopover controller dealloc reached while popover is still visible, and I ran zombies and not exactly sure what to make of the data

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise that your subject was the exception message.  Once I realised that and about it, the problem was obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are dismissing the view without dismissing the popover first.

You can make sure it is dismissed overriding `viewWillDisappear`

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    if (self.popoverController != nil) {
        [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:animated];
        self.popoverController=nil;
    }
 }
```

You should also add the UIPopoverControllerDelegate method `popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:` -

```
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
    self.popoverController=nil;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Your if statement in the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` should be either

```
if ([picker sourceType] == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera){
```

or

```
if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera){
```

You had the ] in the wrong place.

Comment: That worked! One quick followup question, when it dismisses the popover it goes to the previous screen, what should I change so that it stays on the same view controller, and once it does that so the chosen image is shown in the UIImage spot. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I've tried the following code, and it works but I can't declare it twice for both methods and I'm wondering how to implement this.  - (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage * image                 = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]; 
    imageView.image                = image;

Comment: It is going to the previous screen because you are calling `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` - Perhaps you meant to call `self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:` - I was wondering about that.  I am not sure I understand your previous comment.  Are you asking how to have the one class act as a delegate for two `UIImagePickerControllers`?

Comment: Thanks, and yes I want the uiimage to be updated from either a picture that was taken or from the library.

Comment: You can either workout which picker you are handling in the delegate - examine the tag property for example - or create a UIPopoverController subclass to drive your popover and make it the delegate of the ImagePicker.  It will need to pass the selected information back to the main class - You can do this by implementing the `popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover` delegate method and examining a property of your subclass

Comment: Thanks for both approaches! originally I had wanted to implement a popover that would give the user both options and have it choose from there, would that still be able to be implemented?

Comment: Perhaps you could put a tab bar at the bottom of your pop over, or you could add a "camera" icon as the first picture in the image picker and if they select that, then switch to the camera picker

Comment: Thank you! now going back to the other question regarding tags. I've added a self.imagePicker.tag =20; and I get a property tag not found on object of type error

Comment: Sorry, that is my bad.  UIImagePickerControllers don't have a tag property as they aren't a UIView subclass.  You could check the `sourceType` property to work out which picker it was

Comment: Thank you for all your help! and here's what I tried. i get an "expected ']'" error on of the if line, im not sure why. I've edited my code snippet above for easier viewing

Comment: - (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    
    if ([picker sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]){
        UIImage * image                 = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        imageView.image                 = image;
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

        
    }else{
    
        
   UIImage * image                 = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
   imageView.image                 = image;
}

          }

    @end